# What is the purpose of beds in Aquaria?

Tags: aquaria

I have encountered a number of beds and "resting places" in Aquaria, but so far they seem to have no purpose.

They are something you can interact with, the help file even mentions them as an early example of interacting, but nowhere is it mentioned that they have any use.

Other than a small push to the plot (no spoilers) in the beginning they seem to have no point at all. They could not be a save point, there are save crystals for that, and from ***my experience*** they don't seem to regenerate your health.

I have not finished the game, so if a use becomes apparent later in the game, just mention that and I'll be content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never wondered about their purpose. During my playthroughs of the game I never noticed any actual purpose they served, other than some items being placed on them.

Comment: Oh, are they "normal" items that can be acquired elsewhere, or are they special to a certain bed somewhere?

Comment: There are two items I know of that are placed on beds, the [Aquaria-wiki](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Aquaria/Treasures) also lists them: The **Mithala Doll** and the **Girl's Costume**. Both can be acquired on a regular playthrough.

Comment: Oh, so it seems that they just further lend to the story by the items being found on them. That's good enough for me, thanks. :)